# why constructor will call after loading saved components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I put some react components in an array and each time I want to slice from this array and put it in render function, for example:

```
 ...
 MyArray = [Comp1, Comp2, Comp3, Comp4, Comp5];
 render() {
  switch(state.situation){ 
    case 0: 
        return MyArray.slice(0, 3);
    case 1:
        return MyArray.slice(1, 4);
    ...
    }
 }
```

So my problem is when I do the slicing and render it each component will be reconstructed and this is a very slow process because the components' `constructor` is an expensive function to run. How can I prevent the `constructor` from being called multiple times? Is there any way to store a component perfectly? For example, cache the component and render it if it's needed?

Comment: Is the constructor of the component called when you simply pushing it into an array?

Comment: yes , at first I construct the components through another function and then save it to this array @fshock

Comment: It does not seem to be the case. I have built a sandbox trying to understand this issue and it does seem that the constructor is called multiple times. Have a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/l5yk0vk3j9. The constructor is called only once when the case matches

Comment: If you have to add these components, then how about adding them first and via the `state` to control their `visibility`. **React** helps us by `diff` to avoid repainting the whole stuff which is controlled by the `state` inside of the component.